# Filter out text-only spams

Tags: spam-prevention

I have been getting these spam emails that are just text and the spam filter can't seem to do anything about it.  I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that can possibly catch these spams.  Below is couple samples.  I would very much like to hear ideas on how to filter out these nuisance spams that the spam filter can't seem to filter out.

The spams contains just texts and there does not seem to be any particular pattern that I can see.  There is always links, of course.  But, no discernible pattern I can see.  Love to hear ideas on how to filter something like this.

=======================

CBS Report - There are 3 so called “health foods” you should NEVER eat

See them > http://www.cielcardenst.com/881j8x6386eIrTb65xkMhhxvKaFgOUqZtzMhff05/buzzwords-stroker

These are foods that are being marketed to you as super foods for your health.

If you're serious about regaining your health and energy, I urge you to
watch every second of this brief presentation I've made to help you do
just that

Full Story > http://www.cielcardenst.com/881j8x6386eIrTb65xkMhhxvKaFgOUqZtzMhff05/buzzwords-stroker

All statements above are an-ad

go here to end
http://www.cielcardenst.com/af78s6s3x8Y6f_b65KkMhhxvKaFgOUqZtzMhfb45/buzzwords-stroker
218 E.  Bearss Ave. , Ste.  203, Tampa, FL 33613

Discard your email from our database by submitting your name here
http://www.cielcardenst.com/chooses-concretes/9908S9j3870ib65ZkMhhxvKaFgOUqZtzMhf2f1
Eleanor Dimaria / 3308 Lovell Ct Las Vegas Nv 89121-3733

resolute that Dalzell was forced to give ground. As he slowly retreated and shifted, Jetson drove in more impetuously than ever. Midshipman Dan found himself at last in a position of advantage. Now, hammer him, Danny  advised; Farley,

nerve-energy, was now just the least bit confused. Dan landed on one ear, and then against his enemys chin. Both were hard, dazing blows, though neither left a mark. Then an uppercut and Dalzell landed on Jetsons jugular. With, a gasp the fellow went down to the floor. One, two, three, four Hepson began counting. Dont bother

right soon, broke in Dan Dalzell eagerly. Joyce had already stepped into the room, leaving the door open. Now, as though by instinct, the midshipmen seemed aware that the O.C., who to-day happened to be Lieutenant Cotton, U.S.N., was standing in front of the doorway gazing in. Instantly the middies came to the position of

attention, looking straight ahead of them. Good evening, gentlemen, greeted the O.C. Is anything unusual going onWe have been discussing the football situation, sir, announced Midshipman Hepson quite truthfully. Had Hepson been asked if there had recently been a fight in progress he would have answered truthfully, but he

===================================

Did You See What Drastic Things This Mom Did To Her Face? (Photos Included In Article)

Doctors around the world are angry that THIS mother posted her simple facelift trick online. 
(She is 55 but now looks 33)

Only **5** complimentary samples are left.

Please HURRY and read her exclusive story here
http://www.clintoscraziness.com/begotten-breakaway/936E8o634bBNb2imMjjywKbFiOVsav0Mjh1a6

You may stop by going below
http://www.clintoscraziness.com/5edR8m6sk34cKb2MmMjjywKbFiOVsav0Mjhb9d/multi-triplets
Or by writing to PO Box 26383 2700 Louisiana Ave. S. Minneapolis, MN 55426

Take off your account from our listing
by confirming your information http://www.clintoscraziness.com/pertaining-Westfield/31eu89sy3v-4dXb2EmMjjywKbFiOVsav0Mjh14e this way
35 Yosemite Dr Cherokee Village Ar 72529-5219

Comment: Which spam filter do you use?  Which OS/distribution do you use? Which email client do you use?

Comment: I use SpamCombat (https://www.glocksoft.com/spamcombat/) and simple IMAP client on Windows 7.  And Edison email (https://mail.edison.tech/) on iOS & Android.

SpamCombat allows me to write black/white-lists using regular expression.  SpamCombat normally filters out well, except it seem to be defeated by these type of text-only spams.  I'm hoping I can come up withe some sort of blacklist regular expression to filter it out.  If not, I just have to put up with deleting it manually.